# PCB 4-layer cap construction, prepreg mechanical strength

Tags: pcb-layers

I am trying to construct a 4-layer board for an RF application. I have decided to use Rogers RO4350 material due to the high frequency signals on the top layer. I have also considered combining Rogers and FR4 material since the high frequency signals will be only on the top layer (less expensive.) The most suitable stackup for the moment is:

- Rogers RO4350B of 4mil (0.101mm) thickness
- Rogers Prepreg RO4450B of (30mil to 40mil) thickness
- Rogers RO4350B of 4mil (0.101mm) thickness

[image]

As you can see, RO4350 dielectrics are quite thin so we need the prepreg to add mechanical strength on our board. My question is: Since we use a prepreg in the middle instead of a thick core, will the above stackup have an appropriate mechanical strength or should a thick core be used instead of prepreg?

Comment: I'm curious whether 30~40mm was a typo. How do you even make practical vias on a 30mm thick PCB?

Comment: Yes it is a typo. The correct value is 30-40 mils! Thanks for that

Comment: The most qualified to answer your question is your PCB fab shop. I think RO4450B bonds to roughly 4 mils, so you will need 8-10 plys to reach 30-40mils. It sound really expensive and impractical. I have never seen more than 4 plys of prepreg in a stack-up, so it might not even be possible. If it is a requirement to have cores on the outside, consider a six layer stack-up to have a thicker core material in the center as a stiffener. You should consult your PCB fab shop early on in the process. It's a bummer finding out that your PCB cannot be manufactured after you are done designing.

Comment: Thank you! Thank was very helpful

Comment: RO4450B has a thickness of 0.0036" about 10x smaller than listed even after the edit: http://www.agssales.com/ro4400.pdf

Comment: Is this because they use multiple layers to create the prepeg?

Answer (score 1):

The pre-preg is malleable when your PCB fab shops receive it. But after curing (which happens during the PCB manufacturing process), its properties aren't particularly different from a core's.

I wouldn't worry about the difference in mechanical properties after curing unless you have some very special mechanical requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Normally  this stackup  is ok, if your design will work in a special envirment , then you can consider fr4+rogers  hybrid press

this pic  show  Dielectric Strength

[image]

Comment: Where was this figure sourced from? A reminder that all sourced images and quotations must have a citation or source indicated.